# How to automate TC Server war deployment

Tags: maven, tomcat, tcserver

I download TC server **STANDARD** edition on my computer because this is the installed one on QA servers. My final goal is to write a maven task to deploy a war app in a distant tc server's instance.

Because of the use of the standard edition, tomcat manager is not pre-installed (so I cannot use maven's cargo plugin anymore).

So is there any method to deploy my jar in a distant server instance without putting it manually in webapp folder ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a several options:

1) Our latest release 3.2.x (standard) introduced the tomcat-manager template which will set up the Manager webapp and secure it for a production environment.

2) You can also use the developer edition of tc Server.  If it is the same version it will be nearly identical, it just will not contain some of the templates in the standard edition.

3) Add a maven target that copies the Manager webapp to the webapps folder.

Comment: Thank you very much for the first option :)